# xamarin ios : next is gray out in sign and distribute process for IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to publish my app to the App Store following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=vsmac

But i have reached to sign and distribute step and i can't press next(gray out). So please can someone tell me why? and how can solve this issue?

[pleae click here to see picture describing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGlBO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the image you attached, you actually have 2 products, both need signing. One for your main app, and one for your extension. Select your extension, and specify a provisioning profile for that as well (you might have to generate one for that on the Developer portal if you haven't done so already!)